Tool that can recover lost APFS partitions
So there is this machine which was formatted and new OS installed. Tried to reocover partitions using TestDisk. It lists a lot of them but then I cannot preview files as Testdisk does not support APFS. Is there a tool that supports APFS?
Buying is not an issue if I can preview partitions and see the data are at least there, but if there is an awesome software like Testdisk then tha will be great

Which new OS was installed? Feel free to let us know if you have no backups to forestall the inevitable questions about that.

The OS of the lost data machine is MacOS Ventura. I was attempting recovery from Ubuntu Live CD with Testdisk

And... no backups are there

I believe you are out of luck in fall 2024 for any third party repair options for macOS APFS disks.
The Disk Utility tool is the first party and AFAIK, only solution for repairing a disk. We do have many many questions here about rewriting the partition table if you managed to mess that specific part of a disk up.
Search for gpt ffff and edit enough specifics into your post here for an expert to weigh in if you can’t figure out how to “restore” the mapping.
Also, third party disk recovery tools will have good results with APFS, but I don’t think they sell software to the public to do this work, they keep their tools and trade craft to their staff.
Here are links in case you can get their support to confirm they will do what you need:

https://www.prosofteng.com/drive-genius-mac-protection-software
https://www.alsoft.com/
https://drivesaversdatarecovery.com/

Best of luck!

Thanks for the heads up. Until now I have always been successful with Testdisk. It is super easy and does the job well. But alas, it does not support APFS. I don't blame them as the guy have done a great job already. I will try the links

I recently found that Disk Drill could show me previews of files on a damaged APFS-based container/volume: https://www.disk-drill.com

tried to install in boot mode in ventura and it complains Swiftui framework not found

I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AdKVsfCXfo
